# Binary file not executed for web user

Tags: php, bash, apache, shell, perl

I have a php script that creates a shell script file that finally executes as the www-data user, all of the commands are executed except for the last one which implies a binary file. If I run the command as root, it runs ok...

This is the last part of the script:

```
&& echo "Tokenizing the file........" >> Logs/table_of_contents.php \
&& perl ../common/Scripts/xmltokenize.pl --filename=xmlfiles/table_of_contents.xml >> Logs/table_of_contents.php \
&& perl ../common/Scripts/xmlrenumber.pl --filename=xmlfiles/table_of_contents.xml >> Logs/table_of_contents.php \
&& echo "Tagging the file........" >> Logs/table_of_contents.php \

# I have added this line to check if it helps but id doesn't
&& export HOME="/tmp/" \

# And this is the command that calls the binary file
&& perl tagfile.pl xmlfiles/table_of_contents.xml \
```

Here you have the content of the **tagfile.pl**

```
use File::Find;
$\ = "\n";

$fn = shift;

if ( $fn =~ /([^\/\.]+)\.xml/ ) { $fileid = $1; } else { exit;};
print $fileid;

$cmd = "perl tagfl2/makevrt.pl 'xmlfiles/$fileid.xml' > 'tagtmp/$fileid.vrt'";
print $cmd;
print `$cmd`;

#ALL OF THE PREVIOUS WORKS
#THIS IS THE ONE THAT GIVES PERMISSION ERRORS 
# OF COURSE: "www-data:www-data tagtmp/" and "www-data:www-data $fileid.vrt = table_of_contents.vrt"
$cmd = "cut -f 1 tagtmp/'$fileid.vrt' | tagfl2/treetagger/bin/tree-tagger -no-unknown -token -lemma tagfl2/treetagger/lib/english.par  > 'tagtmp/$fileid.tagged'";
print $cmd;
`$cmd`;
$cmd = "perl tagfl2/mrg.pl 'tagtmp/$fileid.vrt' 'tagtmp/$fileid.tagged' > 'tagtmp/$fileid.mrg'";
print $cmd;
`$cmd`;
$cmd = "perl tagfl2/tagxml.pl 'tagtmp/$fileid.mrg' 'xmlfiles/$fileid.xml'";
print $cmd;
`$cmd`;
```

Here is the error:

```
sh: 1: tagfl2/treetagger/bin/tree-tagger: Permission denied
```

Also, just in case:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data tagfl2/
chmod -R g+rwx tagfl2/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, all solved, one thing was giving the file system, actually the mounted unit, the exec attribution.

The second thing was moving **treetagger** directory to `/usr/local/`

Then, at `/usr/local/bin/` I have created a soft link this way:

```
ln -s ../treetagger/bin/tree-tagger
```

Making the binary file globally executable. Actually, this last step was the ultimate solution.

Then at the **tagfile.pl** perl script, the line containing the **tree-tagger** command, I have changed it this way:

```
cut -f 1 'tagtmp/$fileid.vrt' | /usr/local/bin/tree-tagger -no-unknown -token -lemma tagfl2/treetagger/lib/english.par  > 'tagtmp/$fileid.tagged'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a full path to the script

```
$cmd = "perl /[full_path]/makevrt.pl 'xmlfiles/$fileid.xml' > 'tagtmp/$fileid.vrt'";
```

Comment: The one you say it works, it is the next one which doesn't, I will try though! .... it does not work!

Comment: $cmd = "cut -f 1 tagtmp/'$fileid.vrt' | /[full_path]/tagfl2/treetagger/bin/tree-tagger -no-unknown -token -lemma /[full_path]/tagfl2/treetagger/lib/english.par  > 'tagtmp/$fileid.tagged'";

Comment: And there set full path?

Comment: Which line has an error?
Set `die 'here';` after every line while this message are disapear

Comment: The line with errors is the one with the 3 lines of comments before it

Answer (score 0):

Why did you update **user ownership**?
Changing the **group ownership** should have been enough:

```
chgrp -R www-data tagfl2/
chmod -R g+rwX tagfl2/
```

And change the lowercase x by a greater one, to give access/execution permission, only if it is already the case for the user owner (no need to give otherwise).

You may then check the permission like this:

```
su -m -c 'ls -R tagfl2/' www-data
```

And see if you reproduce access issue; and then update permission accordingly.

Comment: I've done as you advice but on `su -c 'ls -R tagfl2/' www-data`  I get **This account is currently not available** and the command does not run anyway

Comment: Ok. Try with additional option -m to preserve the parent environment.
**su -m -c 'ls -R tagfl2/' www-data**

Comment: Well now I see this result tagfl2/:
en.cfg makevrt.pl  mrg  mrg.pl  tagfile.pl  tagged  tagxml.pl treetagger  vrtfiles  xmlfiles ...... etc. (all the files and directories inside tagfl2) included **tagfl2/treetagger/bin:
separate-punctuation  train-tree-tagger  tree-tagger**

Comment: Ok, so it should no more be a permission issue.
Could you use bash +x when executing your script? Or copy/paste the whole script? I guess the issue is somewhere else in your script.

Comment: The shell script that lunches the perl script now starts like this: `#! /bin/bash +x` but still does not work

Comment: No, I meant you must launch the command, prefixing it by bash -x, and sending the output here, to see exactly which instruction is failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182722/discussion-between-andres-chandia-and-bsquare).

Comment: No it wasn't it seems there is a problem with the mounted unity at the virtual server